# Devise + Omniauth, a provider that does not have a callback phase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm writing a forum application that needs to handle both local user accounts (in the database) as well as remote user accounts (on a different service). Here's what I have so far:

- I need to create local users (without passwords?) when a remote user logs in, so I can track forum posts.
- I need to write an Omniauth provider to call out to the remote service to verify authentication data.

Now, the remote provider has an API endpoint that lets me authenticate users by sending a username and password and getting a boolean (true/false) back. My test requests have looked like this:

`POST /authenticate
...other headers...
username=mytestuser@testuser.com&password=testuserpassword`

with a response like this:
`<boolean>true</boolean>`

The XML is easy enough to parse, the only issue I'm having is that Omniauth seems to abstract providers into a `request_phase` and a `callback_phase`. My provider seems to only have a `request_phase`. What should I do? Is Omniauth the correct tool for the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this using a custom Devise strategy, along with the `httpclient` gem. From there, it was as simple as calling out to the API endpoint and parsing the XML to check and see if there was a valid user trying to sign in. I created password-less users on my side if the user had never signed in before.

Comment: any chance you could open source the code that you created to implement this?

Comment: @ryanfelton You'll have to tweak lines 5 and 10, but I was able to put something similar to this in my `config/initializers/devise.rb` and it worked fine: https://gist.github.com/fwilson42/737a5089caa62d855fb9